# Difference between clock cycle, machine cycle and instruction cycle of the CPU

Tags: clock, microprocessor, cpu, instruction-set

There is a lot of ambiguity between the definition of these three terms. So, I wanted to know what is the intuition behind these terms and how all three are connected to each other.

Comment: actually, there isn't any confusion - what they describe is right in their name.

Comment: I didn't understood the intuition behind the terms like what is the need of machine cycle when there is instruction cycle. And what is the significance of clock cycle.

Comment: a "clock cycle" is the period of a clock and can be applied to any clock, an instruction cycle is the time it takes to execute an instruction, and hence can only be applied to processors executing insturctions. The only "hard" term is machine cycle. And different people define that differently – but usually it's the time it takes to push things down the pipeline one pipeline step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Clock cycle**: A clock is simply a (typically periodic) signal used to trigger some regular operation in a system. For example, there's a clock for your CPU's memory bus controller, which typically is different from the clock for your CPU's execution units; this is a very general term, and there's typically *many* different clocks in a complex system such a modern CPU. A clock cycle is just the time between two triggering clock signal events (e.g. rising edges)
- **Instruction cycle**: the time it takes to execute an execution. One or multiple machine cycles, as it's the time between an instruction being fetched and the result of the execution taking effect.
- **Machine cycle**: Ambiguously defined, because the term is older than the fact that basically any CPU you'll find is pipelined. A common definition is that it's the time it takes for the pipeline to advance one step – e.g. for the result of the decode stage to be moved to the first execution stage. This can be one to very many clock cycles of some underlying clock that drives the internal state machines of these pipeline stages.

Note that you'll really want to look at the simplest pipelined CPU architecture you can find to understand these concepts.